# Magento custom email template date format

Tags: php, email, magento

I want to format a date and time directly in my e-Mail Template in Shipping Email about Estimate Shipping Date.

I tried it this way:

**`{{var order.getShippingArrivalDate() format="Y-m-d"}}`**

and this way

**`{{var order.getShippingArrivalDate()|formatDateTime: Y-m-d}}`**

even i tried this way

**`{{var date("d-m-Y",strtotime(order.getShippingArrivalDate()|formatDateTime: Y-m-d))}}`**

but both ways are not working. Is there any possibility to format the date/time directly in the email template?

Comment: this doesn't look like php, but javascript instead. what you should be doing is using the normal function to format a date, and use 'order.getShippingArrivalDate()' as the INPUT of that function.

Comment: it is formatted string to get data of **shipping_arrival_date** column data from object.

Comment: I figured as much, so you can either get that data yourself and format it, or reformat this string. you should be able to use this string as an input for the date function. again this looks like javascript im not sure if that's just a mistake in coding or what. php variables start with $, and generally don't have periods in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento's email template processor is pretty basic and has only a few helper functions, none of which format dates. Instead of formatting the date in the template, format it in the class which sends the emails and pass the formatted value as a parameter to the template.

Alternatively, add a formatting method within the order class (you'll need to rewrite the order model to do so):

```
public function getShippingArrivalDateFormatted ($format)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getShippingArrivalDate(), $format, true);
}
```

And then reference it within the email template:

```
<!--@vars
{"var order.getShippingArrivalDateFormatted('short')":"Arrival Date"}
@-->        

...
<p>Arriving on {{var order.getShippingArrivalDateFormatted('short')}}</p>
```

Comment: You could accept this answer as the solution if it solved your issue.